# Версия приложения VS C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Где в VS можно указать версию приложения или библиотеки разработанной на С++?

Comment: Где угодно можно указать. Надо-то вам что?

Comment: Необходим какой-то стандартный подход, для указания версий приложений, в идеале, чтобы соотносился с системой контроля версий.

Comment: В ресурсы версию пишите

Comment: Как насчет ресурса [VERSIONINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Harry, да, наверное то, что надо.